# Is it possible to scan for security vulnerability of Smart Contract in PHP

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets, php, web3.php

I am trying to use https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php to build an api tool for scanning smart contracts for vulnerbilities.

Ref link: https://ethereum-php.org/dev/

My doubt it is possible to do that?  I have various security tool like mythrill (https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril), Securify (https://github.com/eth-sri/securify2). But those are built on python. I need something to be developed on php or javascript.
Kindly pour some ideas on this. Is it possible to scan smart contracts for vulnerabilities with php?

Comment: It should be possible, PHP is a general purpose computer language. Although I'd say it is impractical having mythril and several other tools rewriting them in PHP isn't very interesting.

Comment: @Ismael Ok, Thanks for the update